# Jupyter Lab not seeing GPU with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have jupyter lab installed on a ubuntu 18.04 server. I've installed a graphics card and installed tenserflow 2.3.1 (per these instructions: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) using python 3.6.9. I had to add the following enviromental variable to /etc/environment get it to work:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64
```

However, Jupyter lab doesn't see me GPU! When I run the follownig commands in a jupyter lab notebook

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices()
```

it returns the following:

**OUTPUT FROM JUPYTER LAB NOTBOOK**

```
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'),
PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:XLA_CPU:0', device_type='XLA_CPU'),
PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:XLA_GPU:0', device_type='XLA_GPU')]
```

But, when I run the same two lines in an ipython notebook (or a python3 interactive shell or from a terminal **in** jupyter lab) I get the following output:

**OUTPUT FROM IPYTHON SHELL**

> 2020-11-28 13:21:39.005815: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1 2020-11-28
>
> 13:21:39.083058: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful
> NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be
> at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero 2020-11-28
>
> 13:21:39.083573: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0
> with properties:  pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2060
> computeCapability: 7.5 coreClock: 1.68GHz coreCount: 30
> deviceMemorySize: 5.79GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 312.97GiB/s
>
> 2020-11-28 13:21:39.083610: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1 2020-11-28
>
> 13:21:39.142212: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10 2020-11-28
>
> 13:21:39.172917: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10 2020-11-28
>
> 13:21:39.180484: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10 2020-11-28
>
> 13:21:39.244521: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10 2020-11-28
>
> 13:21:39.259263: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10 2020-11-28
>
> 13:21:39.370126: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7 2020-11-28
>
> 13:21:39.370414: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful
> NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be
> at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero 2020-11-28
>
> 13:21:39.371750: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful
> NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be
> at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero 2020-11-28
>
> 13:21:39.372808: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible
> gpu devices: 0

> Out[3]: [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'),
> PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:XLA_CPU:0', device_type='XLA_CPU'),
> PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:XLA_GPU:0', device_type='XLA_GPU'),
> PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]

Clearly the ipython/python3 shell sees it, but jupyter lab does not.

I even try setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH *in* jupyter lab via:

```
import os
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64'
```

Still didn't work!

How can I get jupyter lab to see my GPU so I can train my networks on the GPU instead of the CPU?

edit 1: Added clarity to output

Comment: The output shows that jupyter lab does see the GPU, I am not sure what exactly is the problem. Which part of the output "clearly" shows that jupyter lab does not see it?

Comment: The out[3] from above is using the the ipython interactive shell, not the output from the jupyter lab notebook. Did a littler research and 'XLA_GPU:0'  is not a GPU

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Jupyter notebook because I install tensorflow via conda and I need to add the path variable manually. I am also unable to add environment variables in the notebook so I tried to add the variables in `kernel.json` of the jupyter instead and it worked for me. It looks like this:

```
{
 "argv": [
  ...
 ],
 "env": {
    "LD_LIBRARY_PATH":"your_lib_path"
 },
...
}
```